# Cell hidden property [tableView]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have section:1 has 11 rows. I set height like this

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) return 350;
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return 150;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

if I set cell.hidden = YES; how can I remove the cell because if cell.hidden = YES it will be show space but I don't want that space I want if the cell is hidden directly remove from the secrion:1

or if I can set height for every hidden cells for 0.0

Thanks

**EDIT**

there is no NSArray for tableView it is customized like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    if (section == 0) { return 1; }
    else if (section == 1) {

        int retype = [type intValue];

        if (retype == 1 || retype == 5 || retype == 10) {
            return 0;
        }

        else if (retype == 11) { return 9; }
        else if (retype == 14) { return 4; }

        else {

            return 11;
        }

    }
    else return 0;

}
```

and for the cell configure like this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        }

int truef = [*nsstring* intValue];
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
if (truef == 0) {
cell.hidden = YES;
}
else {
cell.titleLabel.text = @"True";
}
}
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This the error after use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

```
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (11) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)
```

Comment: At what point do you decide when to show/display the cell?

Comment: Try getting the cell by calling the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then you could check `hidden` property

Comment: Can you be more specific as to why you want to hide cells ? Do you want to hide things from the user ? The data associated to these cells are no longer needed, or no longer exist ?

Comment: When you hide a cell you must do reloadData (or one of the other reloads) to get the view to fully refresh.

Comment: I think you should re-think the model layer a bit... because you need to store that value on the model layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hide cell. The appropriate way here is to remove this cell from your dataSource and remove it from table view via

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

**EDIT**

Well... you will agree with me that "magical numbers" which you are using is not good way.
I see the following solution here: you put all your numbers which you return in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

into instance variables, like

@property (assign, nonatomic) numberOfRowsInSection0;

than you can decrease this variable and remove the LAST row. In you situation you will be able remove only last row from table view.

**Conclusion**: the solution above just a hack which will allow you to remove only last row in your table. You have to review you code again and change logic in order to use array or any other storage. The table view assumes that you have some data source, but you don't, that is the core of you problem.

Comment: there is no NSArray just customized numbers like Edit see it please

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell.hidden) { return 0.0f; }
```